# Windows 10 BitLocker on bootup presents just a blue screen but no password box or text.

Tags: windows, boot, encryption, bitlocker, disk-encryption

I have a Windows 10 machine that used to work just fine. Now when you do a reboot the password box and text does not show. You can type the password and get enter and it will work.

What would cause the machine to no longer show the password box on bootup or accept a recovery usb key and skip needing a password?

Comment: This is the third question to be asked about this behavior.  It sounds like a common update is causing the problem.  The rest of the users with this question, never really described the problem in any significant detail, nor did they ever try possible soltuion.  If you decrypt the system drive, and encrypt it again, does the problem still present itself?

Comment: @Ramhound I did some searching and I found this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-security/bitlocker-pin-pre-boot-screen-empty/f985c4f6-dd71-4586-bd46-50f513432bb3 -- Go Microsoft again to screw stuff up... This is probably why people are disabling automatic updates.

Comment: I wasn't being critical of this question.  I was making a comment, that this was like the third, Bitlocker password field related question I have seen.  I would still try my suggestion.

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/1101186/bitlocker-not-asking-for-password)

Comment: @FrankThornton I'd rather have a full blue screen rather than a bug that allows secure boot to be bypassed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1714920-windows-10-update-ate-bitlocker

Issue is a Windows 10 update.

Removed update and did a rencrypt and it fixed the issue.

Pushing out and blocking the update on over a 1000 machines. Yay for Mondays.

> Well, it turns out that a cumulative update for Internet Explorer
>   interferes with the blue bitlocker screen on startup.
>
> Affects various flavours of hardware.
>
> On our blank blue screens, if we type the bitlocker password as
>   normal, you can log in fine.
>
> Its Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems
>   (KB3172985) Odd. So, to recap, start your machine. you'll get a blue
>   bitlocker screen - with nothing on it. no text input box, or even
>   text! Type your password in as normal, viola.

Comment: Please quote the relevant information for those in a situation where the link does not work.  [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: [Everyone should be aware that, KB3172985, includes the patch, for the printer driver exploit that exists.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3170005)

Comment: You should be able to install [kb3163912](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3163912) instead.  Do your own research on what is required to fix the Windows print spooler bug.

Answer (score 9):

The fix [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-security/bitlocker-pin-pre-boot-screen-empty/f985c4f6-dd71-4586-bd46-50f513432bb3?page=2) worked for me:

- Open a CMD session as Admin
- Use the command `bfsvc.exe %windir%\boot /v`.
- After a restart, the texts should reappear.

  This fixed the issues for me.

Comment: I edited the answer to make it look better, but feel free to check post history. It was never link only

Comment: @ardaozaki don't accuse people of voting.  I removed my comment since you addresses my concerns.

Comment: @Ramhound you are free to vote as you want, I was just saying that voting without reading is not the best way to vote. I also removed my first 2 comments.

Comment: I read your answer, the original revision was a little sparse, after having read the link.

Comment: Worked for me -- the problem was probably arising from our custom deployment system that creates the EFI startup folder on the ESP with a minimal set of files

Answer (score 4):

Same here:

[image]

Solved this problem using this answer: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-security/bitlocker-pin-pre-boot-screen-empty/f985c4f6-dd71-4586-bd46-50f513432bb3?auth=1

The moment it started talking about **fonts** I realised - maybe everything is working just fine - just the text isn't displayed.

**Type your password as usual and hope Microsoft will update the thing**

Comment: Yep, this was the first thing I tried when debugging first issue. It does work unless your end users are stupid and panic and support calls come in :( But good answer!

Comment: ha! what a great bug

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 2 years of waiting and all windows updates i found a good working solution
It didn't work (bfsvc.exe %windir%\boot /v)
It also didn't work (diskpart select disk 0 select partition 1 assign letter=s: Keep the diskpart window open don't close it yet Open another Admin Command Prompt and overwrite the files in s:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts with your good Truetype files. Or if you prefer rename the old ones to *.bak and then copy your good files here. Back in the diskpart window remove letter=s:)

But this WORKED (plug in a usb stick  example e:, and your disk example c:
1) open cmd in administrative rights
2) type: manage-bde -protectors -add c: -recoverykey e:
so this saves a key to your thumb drive
when restart you  will see a normal screen with text! 
if you want to add or remove password or recoverykey use the same command 
example manage-bde -protectors -delete c: -password

the commands somehow corrects all text
but you can do it also in another way . by  rightclick on disk> manage bitlocker> turn off
then enable again but don't give password. just use a usbdrive to save the key
then use command to add password if you want!
see your protectors with the command:  manage-bde -status
there you can see the protectors used as: password, recoverykey ecc